# Enabling Cephx In cephadm depolyment

Tags: security, authentication, ceph

Hello i am trying to enable cephx in my ceph cluster
i added this three lines to `/etc/ceph/ceph.conf`

```
 auth_cluster_required = cephx
 auth_service_required = cephx
 auth_client_required = cephx
```

i didn't don generate any keyring since cephadm did that for me already.
the problem is after a while this 3 lines automatically gets removed from ceph.conf ;

Comment: Ceph evolved from using the ceph.conf to a [config database](https://docs.ceph.com/en/latest/rados/configuration/ceph-conf/#monitor-configuration-database). Usually, only a minimal ceph.conf required for all nodes and the rest is handled in the config database. The [docs](https://docs.ceph.com/en/quincy/cephadm/operations/#etc-ceph-ceph-conf) also cover how to distribute a copy of the conf file to hosts. So in theory (haven't tried that myself) you should be able to run it like this: `$ ceph config set global auth_client_required cephx` and respectively for the other config options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 auth_cluster_required = cephx
 auth_service_required = cephx
 auth_client_required = cephx
```

this configs should be set on client side not on cluster nodes.

in cluster client config is

> auth_client_required = cephx,none

i don't know a way to force cephx and deny none cephx :/